# Inconsistency in row returns

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

**My question**: I'm wondering why the results from a query from a prepared statement should be inconsistent per run.

**Warning** weird stuff ahead.

I'm on an Oracle database. I'm using the `ojdbc6.jar` driver. I have a query which returns about 1300 rows (it changes over time because there's a `where` clause which depends on `sysdate`). When I run it in Toad (SQL Developer tool) and Netbeans Services tool (Another interface with the database) it works great. My results are consistant. But when I run the query in java code my results are highly inconsistent. In an effort to try and see how frequent each result count returned I put it into a for loop and iterated 10 times. There is a relatively consistent row count within each run, but not across runs. My output and code are below. Let me know whether any more information is helpful.

When an attempt works (sorta...):

```
Got real queries (1308)
Got real queries (1308)
Got real queries (1308)
Got real queries (1307)
Got real queries (1307)
Got real queries (1317)
Got real queries (1317)
Got real queries (1317)
Got real queries (1317)
Got real queries (1315)
```

When an attempt does not work:

```
Got real queries (212)
Got real queries (212)
Got real queries (212)
Got real queries (212)
Got real queries (212)
Got real queries (212)
Got real queries (212)
Got real queries (212)
Got real queries (212)
Got real queries (212)
```

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    List<String> realQueries = new ArrayList<>();
    String sqlAllRealQueries = "select V.SQL_FULLTEXT" + StringHelper.newline
            + "from v$sql v" + StringHelper.newline
            + "where V.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME = 'DSS1_PTC'" + StringHelper.newline
            + "and to_number(replace(replace(replace(v.last_load_time,'-',''), '/',''), ':','')) > to_number(to_char(sysdate - (24/24),'yyyymmddHH24mmss'))" + StringHelper.newline
            + "order by V.LAST_LOAD_TIME desc";
    try (ResultSet rs = getInstance().executeQuery(sqlAllRealQueries)) {
      while (rs.next()) {
        realQueries.add(rs.getString(1));
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Got real queries (" + realQueries.size() + ")");
  }
  System.exit(0);
}

public ResultSet executeQuery(String connection, String query, QueryParameter... params) throws DataException, SQLException {
  Connection conn = ConnectionPool.getInstance().get(connection);
  PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  for (int i = 1; i <= params.length; i++) {
    //... stuff to fill in the '?'s of the query (in this case, there are none).
    }
  }

  ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
  ConnectionPool.getInstance().release(conn);
  return rs;
}
```

Comment: Unless you really need to run with JDBC, it might be better to use a procedure or function.

Comment: @PaulVargas Yeah, I think you're right. I'm giving it a shot now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have small bug in date format 'yyyymmddHH24mmss', should be 'yyyymmddHH24miss'  ("mi" instead of "mm")
mm means month, minutes are "mi".

Comment: Oh wow... How embarrassing... Unfortunately, after changing it, I still get the same problems so that wasn't the problem... I'll give you the acceptance anyway. I decided to go an entirely different route. Thanks for the tip though!